# load phtml file on my blocks in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to load phtml template on my block in magento 1.9 but it is not loading. Here is my code.

app/code/local/Amactech/Events/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amactech_Events>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Amactech_Events>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <model>
            <events>
                <class>Amactech_Events_Model</class>
            </events>
        </model>
        <block>
            <events>
                <class>Amectech_Events_Model</class>
            </events>
        </block>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <events>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <frontName>events</frontName>
                    <module>Amactech_Events</module>
                </args>
            </events>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <events>
                    <file>events.xml</file>
                </events>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

app/design/frontent/base/default/layout/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout version="1.0">
    <events_index_index>
        <update handle="page_two_columns_left" />
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="events/eventblock" />
        </reference>
    </events_index_index>
</layout>
```

app/design/frontent/base/default/template/events/myevents.phtml

```
<h1><strong>My Events.</strong></h1>
```

app/code/local/Amactech/Events/Block/Eventblock.php

```
<?php

    class Amactech_Events_Block_Eventblock extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{

        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->setTemplate('events/myevents.phtml');
        }

    }

?>
```

app/code/local/Amactech/Events/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php

    class Amactech_Events_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
        public function indexAction(){
            $this->loadLayout();
            return $this->renderLayout();
        }

    }

?>
```

Can anyone guide me that where I made mistake because nothing is loaded from phtml template file.

Comment: Do you see the module being enabled in `System > Configuration > Advanced`? Also make sure the output there is not on `Disabled`

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change this:

```
<model>
    <events>
        <class>Amactech_Events_Model</class>
    </events>
</model>
<block>
    <events>
        <class>Amectech_Events_Model</class>
    </events>
</block>
```

to this:

```
<models>
    <events>
        <class>Amactech_Events_Model</class>
    </events>
</models>
<blocks>
    <events>
        <class>Amectech_Events_Block</class>
    </events>
</blocks>
```

and in general check all your code for typos.